# Grayscale convertion using tf.reduce_mean & tf.concat

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

TensorFlow newbie here, training on [a simple tutorial](http://learningtensorflow.com/lesson4/) which I just fail.
The point is to convert an image to grayscale.

Our data is basically an `HxWx3` (height of the picture, width, and color on three values r,g,b).

So it might be equivalent to transform each array cell from `[r, g, b]` to `[gray, gray, gray]` where `gray = mean(r, g, b)` right?

Thus I checked the doc for a mean function and found [reduce_mean](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#reduce_mean).
I used it on the color axis, i.e. axis=2, then concat the result on itself using axis 2 again to "replicate" mean value and finally get 3 times the gray value (=mean) as red, green and blue.

See the code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

filename = "MarshOrchid.jpg"
raw_image_data = mpimg.imread(filename)

image = tf.placeholder("uint8", [None, None, 3])

# Reduce axis 2 by mean (= color)
# i.e. image = [[[r,g,b], ...]] 
# out = [[[ grayvalue ], ... ]] where grayvalue = mean(r, g, b)
out = tf.reduce_mean(image, 2, keep_dims=True)

# Associate r,g,b to the same mean value = concat mean on axis 2.
# out = [[[ grayvalu, grayvalue, grayvalue], ...]]
out = tf.concat(2, [out, out, out])

with tf.Session() as session:
    result = session.run(out, feed_dict={image: raw_image_data})

print(result.shape)
plt.imshow(result)
plt.show()
```

[(You can get original image here)](http://learningtensorflow.com/images/MarshOrchid.jpg)

[image]

This code can be executed but the result isn't ok.

[image: When grayscale fails]

Wondering what happened I check my variables, and it turns out that the mean isn't ok, has shown on screenshot below, mean(147, 137, 88) != 38

[image]

Any ideas?
Can't figure out what I did wrong...

Thanks!
pltrdy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change dtype before computing mean (because of overflow):**

The error come from the dtype of your placeholder. Cause the type inference, intermediate tensors cannot have values greater than 255 (2^8-1). When Tensorflow compute mean(147, 137, 88), first it compute : sum(147, 137, 88)=372, but 372>256 so it keep 372% 256 = 116.

And so mean(147, 137, 88) = sum(147, 137, 88)/3 = 116/3 = 40.
Change the dtype of your placeholder to "uint16" or "uint32".

Result when switching to uint16 (not really convincing right?):

[image]

**Change dtype back to uint8 before plotting it to fit pyplot spec:**

[(see lib doc about imshow)](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=imshow#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow)
Mentions that it must be uint8. For some reasons, using uint16 does not work (and it looks like it reverse color. I mean dark area are white in previous grayscale transformation. Not sure why).

Turning back to uint_ using `tf.cast` just before running (e.g. `out = tf.cast(out, tf.uint8)`) gives the good grayscale transformation below:

[image]

Comment: indeed! Good job & thx. 
Still, it looks like the color are inverted (dark part of image is close to white in grayscale). Strange, i'll investigate, thats another question